# Strain rates of olivine in the upper mantle?

Tags: mantle

Is there any scientific guess/measurement of the average strain rate as a function of depth in the Earth's mantle?
Thinking about mantle convection, I'm curious if there was ever an estimation about the average strain rates that are happening across the mantle. I couldn't find any references for olivine, but maybe someone knows better.

Comment: The average is not a great quantity to consider: Most of the mantle is not experiencing a great deal of shear, but some parts see quite a lot. Why are you interested in the average?